# Password-less login for SSH via SSH

Tags: unix, ssh, ssh-keys

I am writing a script which needs to be able to access a server with limited access. I wish to do this by going through another unix server which I do have access to and also has access to the other computer.

I can SSH into the second machine from home an not be prompted for a password, since I generated an SSH key and using ssh-copy-id. When I am physically at the second machine, I can SSH into the **third** in the same manner, with out being prompted for a password.

However, when I SSH into the second and then try to SSH into the third, I am prompted to the pass-pharse for the key and the password for the third computer.

Why does this happen, and how can I stop this prompt?

EDIT: To clarity some points.

- I do not have root permission on either machine I am SSHing into, only my machine at home
- I missed typed above (now fixed). While physically at the second machine I can SSH into the **third** server.

**Diagram**

```
Machine A : Home machine, root access
|           SSH (passwordless)
v
Machine B : Publicly accessible server, no root permissions
|           SSH (passwordless while physically logged in,
|           password prompted while at machine A SSHed into machine B)
v
Machine C : Only accessable on campus 
            (which B is and A is not), no root permissions
```

Comment: Does password less sash to the third work from anywhere? It's not mentioned in your question.

Comment: Also, I see off topic close votes. I don't believe this is off topic. If you guys want the OP to refine the question, please ask!

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by anywhere. I think that Machine B (see edited question) is the only machine I have access to which can SSH into machine C. I can password-less SSH from Machine B to C while physically at Machine B, not while actually at A and SSHing into B and then trying to SSH into C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention being able to get into the 2nd machine from the 1st, and the 1st to the 2nd. So if there is a 3rd machine in the chain you need to setup SSH keys on the 3rd machine or get the public key off of the 3rd machine you mention.

Another good tip is to manually run SSH with the verbose/debugging (`-v`) option so you can see exactly what is happening at each step.

```
 -v      Verbose mode.  Causes ssh to print debugging messages about its
         progress.  This is helpful in debugging connection, authentica-
         tion, and configuration problems.  Multiple -v options increase
         the verbosity.  The maximum is 3.
```

This has saved me a lot of headaches in the past by showing me exactly how the login process is flowing & what exactly is clogging it up.

So if somehow your 3rd machine is named `machine3.local` then your ssh command using verbose mode would be:

```
ssh -v machine3.local
```

**EDIT:** Original poster says that he is being asked for a passphrase for a key he generated for the 3rd machine. If that’s the case, that’s the problem. You can’t have a passphrase on an SSH key if you want passwordless access.

**ANOTHER EDIT:** Also, be sure they have permissions that match the following & are owned by the account trying to access like this example shows:

```
-rw------- [username] [usergroup] authorized_keys
-rw------- [username] [usergroup] id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- [username] [usergroup] id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- [username] [usergroup] known_hosts
```

Comment: Thank you. I have done is, it appears that the following lines might give some insight into the problem: `debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277 | 
debug1: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed |
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>`. The `|` denote a new line (which I cannot show in a comment). This occurs just before I am prompted to show type my password. Also, I have edited the question slightly as I mistyped a few parts. Thank you again

Comment: I thought I did this while physically at Machine B. I generated an SSH key and used `ssh-copy-id` to put in on Machine C. Also, when I SSH into Machine C from Machine A via B, I am asked `Enter passphrase for key '<home_path>.ssh/id_rsa'`, why would this happen if I have not shared B's public key with C.

Comment: I did not have a password on it, when I am prompted I just hit enter and continue.

Answer (score 0):

Just check for the second computer whether you are logged in as root.
If so then you have to create ssh keys as you did for the user.
Basically, when you are logged in as root again you have to create ssh keys even if you have created it for user.

Comment: I do no have root permissions on either of the machines I am SSHing into. Sorry for not making that clear.